# Sending an sms and email in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, email, vb6, sms

I'm developing a college project in which I'm providing user with a facility to send an SMS and email to its client.

How can I do this in VB or VB.NET ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't done SMS, but here is email using Mail.MailMessage

```
Dim mlItem As New Mail.MailMessage
mlItem.From = New Mail.MailAddress("me@mydomain.com", "Me")
mlItem.To.Add(New Mail.MailAddress("you@yourdomain.com", "You"))
mlItem.Subject = "My Email"
mlItem.Body = "How are you?"
```

Dim mlClient As New Mail.SmtpClient("smtpserver")
mlClient.DeliveryMethod = Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
mlClient.UseDefaultCredentials = False
mlClient.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password", "fqdn")
mlClient.Send(mlItem)

mlClient = Nothing
mlItem = Nothing

Answer (score 2):

I have a [.NET library](http://github.com/johnsheehan/TwilioApi) that will send text messages through [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com) (where I work) in 2 lines of code:

```
Dim twilio As New TwilioApi("youraccountsid", "yourauthtoken")
twilio.SendSmsMessage("555-111-1111", "555-222-2222", "Sending SMS in .NET with Twilio is easy!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Sending emails is quite easy, just look at the `System.Net.Mail` namespace. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) documentation for the `SmtpClient` class has an easy sample.

The easiest way to setup sending SMS would probably be to use an email - SMS gateway, that way you could just send an email for that as well.
Otherwise, [here'](http://www.clickatell.com/developers/vbnet.php)s an SMS gateway that has some sample code for sending SMS via them from VB.Net. (Note, I've no knowledge of that supplier except that they had that sample on their site.).